# Output a series of rows in a column oriented fashion using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to output a number of rows from the database in a form of column oriented "table" perhaps using flex box.

After the nth row I'd like to continue in the next column.

like:

```
1st column
row 1
row 2
row 3

2nd column (right next to 1st column)
row 4
row 5
row 6
```

Could someone please show me an example on how to achieve this (possibly using flexbox)?
TIA

Comment: Post the markup of yours

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Have you tried anything so far? Unfortunately, SO isn't a coding service. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, and eplain the specific problem in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: coding service... :P

Ok... here's what I've ended up with:

`
.qtyList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid #0b4963;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 300px;
}

.qtyListChild {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
`